# Designing an array initialization function which returns pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, templates

I want to design a function which initializes an array and returns pointer to that array.  Using dynamically memory allocation I want to use the same function for initializing an array of 1 dimension, returning pointer to array (*p), and also for initializing an array of 2 dimension, returning double pointer ( **p ).

I've tried to use templates to do this task but I get this error

```
C:/Users/USER/Documents/code_lite/005/main.cpp:61:2: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
  auto **mat1 = initializare<double**, double>(2, 3, 3);
  ^
C:/Users/USER/Documents/code_lite/005/main.cpp:61:54: error: cannot convert 'double**' to 'int**' in initialization
  auto **mat1 = initializare<double**, double>(2, 3, 3);
                                                      ^
C:/Users/USER/Documents/code_lite/005/main.cpp:61:9: warning: unused variable 'mat1' [-Wunused-variable]
  auto **mat1 = initializare<double**, double>(2, 3, 3);
         ^
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
```

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <cstdarg>
 using namespace std;
 template<typename T, typename U>
 T initializare(int num,...)
 {
  va_list list;
  va_start(list, num);
  switch(num)
 {

     case 1:
     {
         // code for array of 1 dimension

         return mat;
     }
     case 2:   //code for array of 2 dimension
        {
         int val=va_arg(list,int);
         T mat = new U *[val];
         T begin = mat;   
         T endm = mat + val -1;

         for(int i=2; i < num; i++)
         {  
          val=va_arg(list,int);
          mat[i] = new U[val];  
          if (mat[i] == NULL)
              exit(1);
          }

          std::cout << "read array  \n";

           for(;begin <= endm; begin++)
           {
             U *bgn =*begin;
             U *end =*begin + val - 1;
              for(;bgn <= end; bgn++)
                std::cin >> *bgn;
             }

          return mat;
       }

       default: // cod for array which has dimension grater than 2

  }
}

int main()
{

  int l1, c1, c2, l2;
  std::cin >> l1 >> c1 >> c2 >> l2;

  auto **mat1 = initializare<double**, double>(2, 3, 3);
 // initializare<type, type>(dimension of array = 2 , number of lines = 
 // 3, number of columns =3  )

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Auto is just shorthand, but the compiler needs to be able to figure it out. You're in effect asking the final pointer to possibly hold two different possible types. I don't think you can really do what you're trying to do, and if I ran into code like this and had to support it, I'd probably be rather unhappy with you, but that's just me.

Comment: I believe the c++ specification already does this. Simply call `T* arr = new T[n]()`

Comment: This code doesn't compile, and it's not for the reasons you mention. At line 17, you're using the variable `mat` without ever declaring it. At line 47, you're missing a statement for the `default` case. Fixing that by adding `return nullptr` in both locations results in a successful compile.

Comment: Why go through all the trouble when you can use `std::vector<std::vector<double>> mat1(3, std::vector<double>(3));`